# How do I retrieve an image uploaded to Amazon S3 via CollectionFS:S3

Tags: javascript, meteor, amazon-s3

In a Meteor project I am using [CollectionFS:S3](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3) to save images to a bucket in S3. I'm not able to see how to load them back into the project.

I have tried to use the FSFile.url() method as show in the code below but it's returning:
/cfs/files/images/e6jQ4Txgvb37GisEQ/imagename.jpg?token=XXX

I was expecting an Amazon S3 url as in s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfolder/imagename.jpg

view.html:

```
  {{#each images}}
    URL: {{this.url}}
    <img src="{{this.url}}" alt="thumbnail">
  {{/each}}
```

view.js

```
 images: function () {
  return images.find();
 }
```

All examples I can see on the CollectionFS github page use the url method so can't see why I'm not able to access the images.

Comment: If it returns data from /cfs directory you probably haven't configured S3 account and your images save locally

Comment: I use it like `<img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/thumbnails/images/{{_id}}-{{name}}" alt="{{name}}">`

Comment: I was using the same collection name as previous one using the cfs:filesystem. It's loading now though the url returned is correct when appended to the meteor app url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually correct. You're getting a url from the server which the server redirects to the correct file on S3.

In other words conceptually the server serves as a proxy to S3 that serves temporary access to files on S3 (hence the token at the end).

If you inspect the image collection server-side (meteor shell) you'll see that it's pointing to the relative path within your S3 collection.

If it's not displaying the image correctly there's something else going on, but it should with the url provided by cfs.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, it loads if I attach that url to the localhost:3000. I've now updated the FSCollection name as it was using the same as a previous one use cfs:filesystem. It's working great now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This how it worked for me.

In client side (template or client folder)
Insure that **store** variable is defined before, and has corresponding values. Should be the same names as you defined them in S3 configuration. Example:

```
store = {
  bucket: 'my bucket name',
  folder: 'folder name where files are stored'
}
```

Define S3Url function:

```
FS.File.prototype.S3Url = function(storeName) {
  var self = this;
  var store = self.getCollection().storesLookup[storeName];
  var urlHost = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/';
  var urlPath = [store.bucket, store.folder, this.copies[storeName].key].join('/');
  return urlHost + urlPath;
}
```

After use it like:

```
{{#each images}}
    URL: {{this.S3Url}}
    <img src="{{this.S3Url}}" alt="thumbnail">
{{/each}}
```

Hope it helps.

PS. Insure that store.bucket and store.folder are set in the Client.

Comment: Nice work. Which file & directory did you save this FS.File.prototype.S3Url code to?

Comment: Thanks Kostanos, but I think I should've reworded my original comment so that you understood better. Regarding the S3URL function that you're writing to extend the FS.File module, where did you put this code? (what file name and path?). Sorry for the confusion.